# Почему и как нужно использовать метод простой итерации в коде?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, visual-studio-2017, численные-методы

[image]

Вот код но, в нем есть ошибки,и он написан не до конца , как сделать правильно?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);
double x , i;
  int f , E;
cout << "Введіть x" << endl;
x = 2 - log(x);
pow(x, 0) = 2.0;
pow((x, i + 1) = f * (x, i));
i = 0, 1, 2...;

return 1
}
```

Comment: Это что-то особенного! xʲ — это не x в степени j, а j-е приближение значения x...

Comment: Там x в степени i . Как написать код правильно , по тому что обведено на фотке?

Comment: Там **НЕТ** возведения в степень!!! Что такое индекс — вы знаете?

Comment: Интересно посмотреть, с какой планеты автор этого задачника. Ну или тот, кто его  верстал-набирал.

Comment: gbg я не знаю как правильно решить это задание , я знаю что код не совсем неправильный вот и решил спросить как правильно его написать . Поможете ?

Comment: @gbg Мне интереснее ВУЗ, курс и специальность :) Просто мой малой в этом году поступил на кибфак, надо его учебники пошмонать малость... что там у него пишут? :)

Comment: @gbg ничего очень странного тут не вижу. Разумеется, лучше чтобы было `x^{(i)}` (в синтаксе латекса), но я часто видел и обозначение итерации без скобочек. Из контекста эта абсолютно всегда четко ясно.

Comment: @AntonMenshov тут по контексту `x_{(i)}`. А если где такое же  в неоднозначном контексте?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie не очень понял вопроса. Именно так. по контексту тут итерация, а не степень. Я и говорю, что по контексту это обычно понятно и редакторы иногда бывают ленивы ставить итерации в скобочки (что является более распространенной и, на мой взгляд, точной конвенцией). gbg говорил, что не знает с какой планеты верстальщик — я лишь говорю, что не вижу ничего экстраординарного.

Comment: @AntonMenshov верстальщик != не автор. Это тот кто  текст на странице выравнивает. Они как раз ничего менять не должны. Здесь грубая ошибка пропущенная науч. и тех. редом, если у издающих они были они конечно)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie  вы ни разу не видели когда итерацию обозначали `x^{i}` вместо более строгого, корректного и широко распространенного `x^{(i)}`? К сожалению, такое сплошь и рядом. Однако конкретно эта проблема всегда решаема из контекста и не создает неудобств.

Comment: @AntonMenshov видел в скобках, но в областях свзанных  с экспертными системами (и там это не совсем индекс итерации, это индекс в множестве) это нестандарт для математической итерации. Суперскрипт индексы без скобок - может означать только степень. И появляющиеся примеры обратного - это как раз признак отсутсвия научных редакторов. Если погуглить, можно найти много жалоб на это за рубежом. А распространяется копи-пастой.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130755/discussion-between-anton-menshov-and-swift-friday-pie).

Comment: Не редактируйте старый вопрос, а задавайте новый. Теперь ответ и комментарии не имеют смысла

Comment: Пишет , что лимит по вопросам достигнут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это что-то особенного! xʲ — это не x в степени j, а j-е приближение значения x...

Ваши попытки `pow(x, 0) = 2.0;` — это примерно то же самое, что и написать `2*2 = 5`, т.е. присвоить не переменной! числу! некоторое значение.

Зачем вы вводите начальное значение x? оно задано в условии...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 2,
        y = 3,      // в принципе, неважно - лишь бы подальше от x
        eps = 1e-8; // Точность - в задании не указана, взял такую.
    while(fabs(x-y)>eps)
        x = 2 - log(y = x);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "2 - log(x) = " << 2 - log(x) << endl;
}
```

Comment: @ Harry это уже весь код к заданию ?

Comment: А чего не хватает? Корень с точностью 0.00000001 найден, что еще?